# Can a point and a direction vector represent a line?

Tags: vector-analysis

I understood that to represent a plane all that is needed is a point a direction vector.
But [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFunctions.aspx) it represent a line, how could it be?

[image]

Comment: For a plane, you need a point and *two* independent direction vectors. For a line you need a point and only one direction vector.

Comment: A plane is represented by a point on the plane and $normal$ vector. A point and a direction gives a line.

Comment: @Bernard or one direction vector if it is the normal vector?

Comment: I'd call it a *normal* vector, not a *direction* vector.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a point and a vector can represent both a plane and a line, using two different interpretations. The representation of a line is shown; the represented plane is the plane passing through the point with that vector as a normal vector.